# How to play gif with Fabricjs?

Tags: fabricjs, gif

I know fabricjs can play Video and sprite sheet, But I have a lot of gif files, can I play these gif directly with fabricjs? I am not able to find method in Fabricjs website.

Comment: [Issue](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/560) is still open in github. Check that.

Comment: requestAnimationFrame may help you

Answer (score 0):

According to specs about the Canvas 2DRenderingContext drawImage method,

```
Specifically, when a CanvasImageSource object represents an animated image in an 
HTMLImageElement, the user agent must use the default image of the animation (the one 
that the format defines is to be used when animation is not supported or is 
disabled), or, if there is no such image, the first frame of the animation, when 
rendering the image for CanvasRenderingContext2D APIs.
```

This means that only the first frame of our animated canvas will be drawn on the canvas.
This is because we don't have any control on animations inside an img tag.

And fabricjs is based on canvas API, thus regulated by the same rules.

The solution is you need to parse all the still-images from your animated gif and to export it as a sprite-sheet. You can then easily animate it in fabricjs thanks to the sprite class.